# Referencing an existing Excel object

Tags: powerpoint

I have an existing PowerPoint where several slides reference the same Excel spreadsheet that is embedded in the file.

I want to reference the same file in a new slide, but copying and pasting as object does not seem to work.

I tried going to the 'Insert' ribbon and selecting the 'Object' button. This did not allow me to reference an Excel object that already exists in the PowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

You need to work through the Shapes.OLEFormat property, which allows you to run Activate and DoVerb:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).OLEFormat.Activate
```